# AmazonMQ RabbitMQ shows less RAM than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

I created AmazonMQ RabbitMQ broker of **mq.m5.large** size. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/broker-instance-types.html#rabbitmq-broker-instance-types) it must have **8Gb** of memory. But when I go to the *Process statistics* of the node in *RabbitMQ Management Console* I see that memory limit is **3Gb**. What's the problem here? Is there anything wrong with *vm_memory_calculation_strategy*?

[image]

Comment: What is the `vm_memory_high_watermark` configuration value?

Comment: @LukeBakken I don't see a way to check it in the web ui. And, since it's a managed AWS service, I don't have an access to the VM itself. As I see in RabbitMQ documentation the default value is 0.4. Having 3Gb makes sense then.

Comment: @LukeBakken pointed to the RAM setting https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#threshold